Blazor site in Azure Static site 404 when entering via address bar
I have deployed a new Blazor site to Azure static web app.
https://www.trevorbollenart.co.uk/
Works well but I have noticed that IF i naviagte to the about page (https://www.trevorbollenart.co.uk/about) via the nav menu it loads BUT if I try and enter via address bar I get a 404? Weird?? Does this for all the URL's, is this normal?
Does not happen when i run local from VS.

Please add staticwebapp.config.json file to your project root directory.

I am able to access even if i enter it manually.
